# How to filter ArrayList<myDataClass> through only one item type of that data-class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

I'm new to this. Is it possible to filter ArrayList's "one part"?

In my UserDto.kt file I have defined my data class:

```
data class  UserDto (val mainWordSplit: String, val defnSplit: String)
```

Now in my MainActivity.kt file I have created ArrayList with UserDto type and put things inside:

```
private var enPairs = ArrayList<UserDto>()
...
var onePair = UserDto(mainWordSplit, defnSplit)
enPairs.add(onePair)
```

where mainWordSplit and defnSplit are Strings.

Now I want to filter through "enPairs" considering only "mainWordSplit" part of the list. Do I have to make another list of only mainWordSplit items, filter it and then remember indexes or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin has a extension function that you can use - [filter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-filtering.html)

Here's an example:

```
enPairs.filter { it.mainWordsSplit == "whatever you want to keep " }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :). "it.mainWordsSplit" was the part!